# Close recently opened process in .sh

Tags: bash, shell-script, process, firefox, kill

I am new to Linux and trying to learn how to launch and close processes automatically. Eventually I would like to run this/a similar process with cron. Here, just testing "checking in" to google.

`gcheck.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash/
export DISPLAY=:0
firefox --new-window https://google.com
```

I have added execute permissions to `gcheck.sh` with `sudo chmod a+x`.
I know that `$$` will give the PID of the script, but how can I get and kill the PID of *just* opened firefox window (in case I have other firefox windows open)?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't think you can, not with `firefox --new-window`, anyway.   `firefox` may not even start a new process for a new window (in my minimal & limited testing, it doesn't, at least not in any way that I can distinguish it from other firefox PIDs).   It should be possible with `--new-instance`, that **will** be a new process, but you'd have to use a different profile (firefox's `-P` option) too, firefox won't open a new instance of an already running profile.

Comment: Read `man pgrep`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting my desired behavior through the following:

```
#!/bin/bash/
export DISPLAY=:0
firefox --new-instance -P chemicalwill https://google.com &
PID=$!
sleep 30
kill -15 $PID # kill -9 also works
```

Using `--new-instance` and a separate profile (here `chemicalwill`) allows me to run other processes under my default profile and not worry about this script killing them off.

Answer (score 1):

Add a & sign to run in background then use pidof command to get the pid like
Code :

```
（firefox --new-window https://google.com　＆）&> /dev/null
 kill -9 $(pidof "firefox --new-window https://google.com")
```

Comment: This approach will work with many programs, but not with `firefox --new-window`.  Firefox does not start a new process for each window or URL.  It pre-forks a bunch of processes when it starts up, and assigns a new window or new URL to one of those existing processes.